# Is JR Pass validity period inclusive?

Tags: japan, jr-passes

Will I be able to board on Hikari Shinkansen at Oct, 26 daytime by my 1 week JR Pass if I activate it on Oct, 20?

I'm almost sure that the answer is 'yes', but asking just to confirm - as I'm planning an expensive trip on Oct, 26.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes

If you have a 7 day Japan rail pass, you are guaranteed to travel for 7 whole days. Then if you activate JRPass on Oct 20th, you can travel from Oct 20th 00:00 to Oct 26th 23:59.

Answer (score 2):

When you activate your pass, they will put a large sticker on it mentioning the first and last days, and yes it is inclusive. The image below shows an activated 7-day JRP valid from 19 to 25 january 2017. That means the owner of this JRP could have used it with no limits including on the 19.01 and 25.01 dates.

[image: japan rail pass]

Answer (score 0):

"if I activate it on Oct, 20" makes no sense. If you mean "if I *exchange* it on Oct. 20", the answer is that it depends on when the validity period starts. If you mean "if *the validity period starts* on Oct. 20", then yes.